# Get item count from SQL android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have an SQL database on my app.

As the title says, how can I get my item count?

My app gets an input from the user and stores in the database, and displays it.

```
MainActivity.java

String task = inputField.getText().toString();
Log.d("MainActivity",task);

helper = new TaskDBHelperHome(MainActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.clear();
values.put(TaskContractHome.Columns.TASK, task);

db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContractHome.TABLE, null, values,
        SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
updateUI();
```

.

```
TaskDBHelperHome.java

public class TaskDBHelperHome extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDBHelperHome(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContractHome.DB_NAME, null, TaskContractHome.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                "%s TEXT)", TaskContractHome.TABLE,
                        TaskContractHome.Columns.TASK);

        Log.d("TaskDBHelper","Query to form table: "+sqlQuery);
        sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContractHome.TABLE);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
}
```

.

```
TaskContractHome.java

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class TaskContractHome {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "home";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE = "tasks";

    public class Columns {
        public static final String TASK = "task";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    }
}
```

I want to know how I can count items in the database.
(I mean programmatically) Thanks.

Comment: downvoted for lack of trying. look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: Did you try `SELECT Count(myColumn) AS someAlias FROM myTable`? `AS someAlias` is optional (but I'd recommend it).

Comment: Sorry, I know seriously small amount of database :(

Comment: thats why we are gently suggesting you use google before posting here.

Comment: @abforce - http://www.troll.me/images/walter/calmer-than-you-are.jpg

Comment: Maybe use a ormlite or greenDao help make it simple and clear

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table_name]
```

---

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable", null);
c.moveToFirst();
int itemsCount = c.getInt(0);
c.close();
```

Comment: Where can I execute the statement?

Comment: @BedrockDev Wherever you want to get count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int totalCount = 0;
    String query = "select COUNT(*) from apartments";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        totalCount = cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    return totalCount;
```